# Can a View have a controller in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

So I have a route as below where the user can get information which the controller fetches and displays. However I want to be able to display this is a nice template page instead of the actual raw data from the controller. How can I do this:

```
Current route:

Route::get('/{region}/{summoner}', 'ApiController@doTest');
```

I should be able to add a blade template to this right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's how Laravel and pretty much every PHP framework work. You do some job in your controller and return data in a view. Just do this in you `doTest()` method:

```
public function doTest(){

    $someDataFromController = 'It's some data from doTest method!';

    return view('someView', ['someDataFromController' => $someDataFromController]);

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#view-responses

Comment: @Elevant, yes, `return view` kind of generates actual HTML page, in which you're inserting data, generated by a controller.

Comment: Thanks mate it's been a while since I have used laravel so glad. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Data to the view while returning the view in your Controller

Eg.
in your API Controller you can have a method like this

```
public function doTest(Request $request){
    ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return view('pages.viewName',$data);
    //OR
    return view('pages.viewName', compact('data');
}
```

on your view you can show the data using Loop or directly
Eg.

```
@foreach($data as $record)
   {{ $data['field'] }}
@endforeach
```